# How to initialize log4j system for entire project at one place?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, log4j

In my project, I've to use `log4j` but in every class, I've mention following -

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(<className>.class);
PropertyConfigurator.configure(<pathOfLog4jPropertiesFile>);
```

Line #1 must be in every class as it talks about the class itself but line #2 is duplicated in every class as it is same across all classes.

Is there any way we can have that configuring properties file at once place and need to write it in every class?

Please do suggest if there is any other better way with which I can use log4j.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass an arg at startup -Dlog4j.configurationFile=

Ensure that all dependencies are in place for your libraries which might be using slf4j or other such logging apis.